# Changed my facebook password - would this cause openid to break?

Tags: support, openid, login

Having some issues.... Normally I am JPH - apparently user1557370, logging in through facebook - but had to change facebook password recently - and since then SE etc. isn't working so well - it keeps logging me in automagically - but not properly - since it doesn't recognise any of the accounts on stack overflow etc i normally have.

is there something I need to do to refresh the openid-or is it a short term bug in SE - or what?

Comment: You can try adding other (maybe dummy) OpenID login, remove the Facebook login and add it back. Can't think of any other way to "reset" such things.

Comment: Hmmm. Added googlemail version and deleted facebook, then did reverse.  Seems like the 'login' has calmed down now - the sub stack exchange sites are working - but the main one doesn't seem to be linking them all together in the normal way...

Comment: Weird... you get any errors at some point?

Comment: Maybe the linking might be related the Inbox problems the sites are/were facing? I'd say: clear all browser data (for the SE sites). (And probably not useful, but just one click: see also the automated test on [Network Login Troubleshooting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help).)

Comment: Looks like you were right arjan.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. OpenID works like this: You log in to FB or your openID provider, and SE connects with it to try verifying your account. The only information SE gets is your email address. SE won't know your password, and it doesn't matter if it gets changed. As long as you are logged in to FB, you can log in to SE. (Also, if you log out, you can log in to SE by first logging in to FB).

The network autologin is rather unpredictable--log in normally on those sites at least once and then the autologin will probably start working.

Answer (score -1):

Ok... looks like it was some problem with stack exchange....

Thanks for the help.